# Keeping Local Version of File Variants from Different Branches

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to Github.

I have a script which I'm developing in which I have different values for some variables and in some cases code variations.

I have found that if I have a master branch and another branch, if I have a cmd window open, I can switch back and forth locally between the version of my script in one branch and the other (`git checkout master`, `git checkout alternatebranch`).  The file in my explorer is the same file and I have one set of repository files, but depending on the branch I'm in locally i have different visible code based on work in the master or alternativebranch and whether I'm 'pointing' to one branch or the other.

If I want to run the script versions concurrently (say in Python in different IDE instances), how can I manage this using the github files?

I am developing i a Windows 7 environment, the script is in Python 2.7, and I'm using Spyder IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to run two different versions of the same script in two contexts, and the versions are in separate branches? Is it only the script you need, or the entire repo?

Comment: Yes on your clarification.  I want to keep/run separate versions of the script.  I don't think I need duplicates of the entire repo.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Git won't help you directly here—but see `git worktree add` below.

If your program reads and/or writes a file named `./control.info` from your work-tree, the contents of `./control.info` are up to your OS and your program.  Git only writes things into the work-tree, or reads things out of the work-tree, when you tell it to do so—all of *Git's* files are stored in special compressed formats, read-only in the repository proper and read/write in Git's index.

Git makes new commits out of whatever is in the index.  When you use `git add` on a file, you tell Git to copy the file from the work-tree—where it has the normal, uncompressed format for ordinary files—into the index, compressing it into the special Git-only format.  When you use `git commit`, you tell Git to package up the index into a permanent commit, with your name as author and committer, and so on.

When you run `git checkout <commit>`, Git figures out which files must *change* in the index, and as a bonus side effect, in the work-tree, in order to switch from whichever commit you have out right now, to the given `<commit>`.  Git will write the updated files into its index (this is very fast) and simultaneously, to the work-tree (a bit slower), and now you have the file in a form usable by non-Git programs.

Git since version 2.5 *does* offer a new command, `git worktree`, that can add additional work-trees to one (shared) repository.  Using this trick, you can have one work-tree checked out at the tip of branch `master`, and a separate work-tree, in a separate location, checked out at the tip of branch `alternatebranch`:

```
git checkout master
git worktree add /C/path/to/different/dir/project alternatebranch
```

for instance.

There have been fixes in `git worktree` since it went in, but the biggest ones were in by Git 2.6, so 2.6-or-later is best for using `git worktree`.